# How to estimate oxygen consumption of an average human during different activities?

Tags: physiology, human-physiology, breathing, exercise

I've tried to find some resource on the internet but had little luck. I'm looking to see if there's any data on average oxygen consumption of average to well trained humans during different activities.

Specifically how much more oxygen does a human consume when panicked/under pressure in comparison to other activities such as cooking, climbing etc. Even better would be if I had a formula where I could plug in weight, height, gender and receive a percentage of how much more O2 is consumed under stress/panic vs. normal functioning. Any information would be much appreciated, please include sources where possible.

NOTE: With "panicked" I mean in the state of fearing for ones safety and being in a life threatening situation with the associated hyperventilation etc.

Comment: https://i.redd.it/expf3tuhr2g01.png panicked is a vague measure, ranging from momentarily startled to buried in an avalanche.

Comment: Yeah panicked is maybe too broad, I mean like you're in a life or death situation

Comment: may be helpful. https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/1469-8986.3860961

Comment: So “average to well trained” is the average overweight shopper to the well trained sprint cyclist?